# Iterator not working

Tags: java, collections

The following code is taking the values properly but not printing the total number of elements. The output is always missing one element.

```
package com.java.arraylist;

import java.util.*;

public class ArrayList_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList_1 obj = new ArrayList_1();
        obj.readList(arrayList);
        obj.displayList(arrayList);
    }

    private void displayList(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        Iterator<String> it = arrayList.iterator();
        System.out.println("Entered Array List elements are : ");
        while(it.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
    }

    private void readList(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many elements are you going to put in this list?");
        int end = scanner.nextInt();
        int start = 1;
        System.out.println("Enter the elements to be added");
        while (scanner.hasNext() && start < end) {
            String item = scanner.next();
            arrayList.add(item);
            start++;
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: How many elements are you going to put in this list?
2
Enter the elements to be added
hello
hi
hey
Entered Array List elements are : 
hello
hi

Answer (score 3):

Your while loop in `readList` is off by 1.

For example, when `end` is 1, you never enter the `while` loop (since 1<1 is false), so you don't read anything.

Either initialize `start` to 0 or change the end condition to `start <= end`.

EDIT :

Change your condition to :

```
while (start <= end && scanner.hasNext())
```

since `scanner.hasNext()` may block while waiting for input to scan.

This way, when `start <= end` is false, the loop will end without calling `scanner.hasNext()`.

Comment: If I initialize the start to 1 and change the condition to start<= end, the console is asking for 3 values and printing 2 values.

Comment: @NaveenMandadhi How are you entering your inputs? Single line? Multiple lines?

Comment: single line inputs

Comment: @NaveenMandadhi Can you add to your question some sample input and sample output?

Comment: How many elements are you going to put in this list?
2
Enter the elements to be added
hello
hi
hey
Entered Array List elements are : 
hello
hi

Comment: @NaveenMandadhi Is that the desired output or the actual output you got? This output looks correct to me.

Comment: I'm only going to enter 2 values, but the console keeps waiting for me to enter the 3rd value and one I enter the third value it displays two values from the entered three vlaues.

Comment: @NaveenMandadhi Do you hit enter after entering the second value?

Comment: yes, and it takes the third value then stops asking me for more values. Only then it goes to the display method.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was in the While.
Here's a working example:

```
private void readList(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many elements are you going to put in this list?");
    int end = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the elements to be added");

    for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
        String item = scanner.next();
        arrayList.add(item);
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  while(start<=end){
        String item = scanner.next();
    arrayList.add(item);
    start++;        
}

or

 for(int i=0;i<end;i++){
    String item = scanner.next();
    arrayList.add(item);

}
```

Thanks,
Amit Kumar